# Flutter: Not able to use Google and Facebook plugins together

Tags: facebook, flutter, authentication, google-signin, flutter-facebook-login

This is the first time in my life that I am asking a question in a forum. I am really desperate. I have added Google Signin with the plugin google_sign_in: ^4.5.6 to my app but as soon as I add the plugin flutter_facebook_auth: ^2.0.0+1 or flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0 and I start my app, I get the following error:

MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences))

Please help me! Thank you so much!

UPDATE: Flutter clean or rebuild did not help

Comment: Just stop and rebuild the app.

Comment: No that did not help. As well as clean and get packages.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter clean` (or remove your build manually). If u are on IOS run `pod install` and then and `flutter run`

Update 1: Check if the Shared Preference plugin has been already registerd inside the `GeneratedPluginRegistrant` ?

Comment: unfortunately not solving the issue

Comment: I am not using the shared preference plugin and the error must come from the facebook plugin because it started after i added the facebook plugin

Comment: Could you create a fresh pj with only the fb dependency to see if the issue is there ?

Comment: as soon as i remove the google sign in plugin the error goes away. just the 2 plugins together do not work

Comment: Try to add the `shared_preferences ` to pub.yaml and see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter clean (or remove your build manually). If u are on IOS run pod install and then and flutter run

Comment: unfortunately not solving the issue

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. please describe your answer, please visit this link how a good answer  https://stackoverflow.com/conduct . thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the reason you first need to `Flutter clean` and `pub get` and then `pod install` still issue is not solved then try with `flutter clean` then `restart IDE` and `pub get`. This will works for you.

Comment: pub get is not working for me, it says zsh: command not found: pub

Comment: Have you installed dart SDK and set the path correctly? @denniskelling

Comment: not sure but my app ran perfectly before adding the facebook plugin

Comment: i just checked it and i have the dart SDK installed and set path correctly

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find two versions of the plugins that work together. I had the same problem and I fixed by using these versions:

```
  flutter_login_facebook: ^0.2.1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.6
```

I also suggest you to watch these videos, that will help you to correctly setup both
`Facebook` and `Google` sign in:

`Facebook sign in with Flutter and Firebase by Andy Julow` - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uYO2ht5Nl4

`Google sign in with Flutter and Firebase by Andy Julow` - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uYO2ht5Nl4

I also had problems with implementing these sign in options at the same time and these videos helped me.